# How can I attach an event handler to the process's exit in a native Node.js module?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I'm working on implementing correct memory management for a native Node.js module. I've ran into the problem described in this question:
[node.js native addon - destructor of wrapped class doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696706/node-js-native-addon-destructor-of-wrapped-class-doesnt-run)

The suggested solution is to bind the destructors of native objects to `process.on('exit')`, however the answer does not contain how to do that in a native module.

I've taken a brief look at the libuv docs as well, but they didn't contain anything useful in this regard, either.

NOTE: I'm not particularly interested in getting the `process` object, but I tried it that way:

```
auto globalObj = NanGetCurrentContext()->Global();
auto processObj = ::v8::Handle<::v8::Object>::Cast(globalObj->Get(NanNew<String>("process")));
auto processOnFunc = ::v8::Handle<::v8::Function>::Cast(processObj->Get(NanNew<String>("on")));
Handle<Value> processOnExitArgv[2] = { NanNew<String>("exit"), NanNew<FunctionTemplate>(onProcessExit)->GetFunction() };
processOnFunc->Call(processObj, 2, processOnExitArgv);
```

The problem then is that I get this message when trying to delete my object:

```
Assertion `persistent().IsNearDeath()' failed.
```

I also tried to use `std::atexit` and got the same assertion error.

So far, the best I could do is collecting stray `ObjectWrap` instances in an `std::set` and cleaning up the wrapped objects, but because of the above error, I was unable to clean up the wrappers themselves.

So, how can I do this properly?

Comment: Is your question it about registering the handler or about getting the `process` object? And what version of node.js are your using (do you want to target `0.10.x`, `0.12.x` or both)?

Comment: @t.niese I'm not interested in getting the `process` object, just to be able to register an event when v8 stops, so I can delete the objects that v8's GC didn't delete. I'd prefer a solution that works over multiple versions of node, but I use `0.12.x`

Comment: Even if there is an internal/direct way inside of V8 to listen for the exit, I still would use the equivalent way you would do in js, by registering  an event handler directly on `process.on('exit')`. And therefor you would need to get the `process` object and call the `on` function on it passing your wrapped callback.

Comment: To create module that will run on different version of node you should take a look at [nan](https://github.com/nodejs/nan), because there are big changes between the different versions of node.

Comment: @t.niese I'm already using Nan, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the `"Assertion persistent().IsNearDeath()' failed"` message.

There is a `node::AtExit()` function that runs just before Node.js shuts down - the equivalent of `process.on('exit')`.

Pass a callback function to `node::AtExit` from within your add-on's init function (or where ever is appropriate).

The function is documented here:
https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_atexit_hooks

For example:

```
NAN_MODULE_INIT(my_exports)
{
// other exported stuff here
    node::AtExit(my_cleanup);
}

NODE_MODULE(my_module, my_exports) //add-on exports

//call C++ dtors:
void my_cleanup()
{
    delete my_object_ptr; //call object dtor, or other stuff that needs to be cleaned up here
}
```